# “No pubspec.yaml file found” in flutter?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run `flutter pub get` to get the packages then i get the following error:

```
error: no pubspec.yaml file found. this command should be run from the root of your flutter project.
```

Anyone came across this before?
Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have actually opened the root folder.
If it looks like this

```
lib
   main.dart
   file1.dart
   file2.dart
   file3.dart
   ...
```

then you have not opened the root folder.
The actual root folder is the parent folder of the directory.


if it looks looks this

```
proj_name
   android
   ios
   lib
   pubspec.yaml
   ...
```

then try running `flutter downgrade` in your command prompt.
It happened with me once and `flutter downgrade` worked.

Comment: Thank you very much. i thought that i was already in the root folder, but i wasn't

Comment: No problem at all. I accidentally have done this twice and it took me forever to realize that. I know how frustrating and confusing it can be

Answer (score 0):

You can use **flutter clean** command and then try

**flutter run** In your terminal

or

Error: No pubspec.yaml file found. This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.

It Simple means that your terminal is currently not in your flutter project the path of the directory is wrong,

Solve it by navigate to the flutter folder change directory Eg : cd portfolio

after changing the terminal directory path

C:\Android Studio Stuff\Flutter Project\portfolio> // your command